# Laravel - Filter out 'null' values from request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, filter

I am attempting to filter my `$request` to not include any input data where the `qty` field is null (`qty` sits on a pivot table)

I have already attempted:

```
$qty = $request->input('qty'); //define qty

$filtered = $request->filter(function ($qty, $key) {
   return $qty != null;
});

$filtered->all();
```

but I receive the error `Method Illuminate\Http\Request::filter does not exist`, which is strange because I have `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in the Controller.

Although I have never filtered data before so I don't know if this is even the correct approach.

Comment: there is one function available in laravel nova 3 
$request->filters()
but its not available in nova 4 does any know what alternative i can use for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty positive the `$request` instance doesn't have a filter method. I think you can achieve what you want using the `collect` helper:

```
$input = collect(request()->all())->filter(function($value) {
    return null !== $value;
})->toArray();
```

**Update:** As of Laravel 8.62.0 the `collect` method exists on the request:

```php
$input = request()->collect()->filter(function($value) {
    return null !== $value;
})->toArray();
```